# Setting Elastic Beanstalk environment variables from deployment hook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**Objective:**

I would like to set a deployment timestamp as an environment variable from a deployment pre deployment hook

**Tried:**

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/00_set_deploy_time.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      export DEPLOY_TIME=`date +%s`
```

`DEPLOY_TIME` dosen't get set.

---

Worst case scenario I can write the deployment time to a random text file. However, since my app is going to be reading this variable frequently, it's not the preferable option.

Comment: EBS == Elastic Block Store, not Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: whoops, i edited the title

Comment: You could try appending the variable to `/etc/profile.d/eb_envvars.sh` where the rest of the EB variables are set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ended up just writing the timestamp to a random file

`.ebextensions/00_set_deploy_time.sh`

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/00_set_deploy_time.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      touch /var/app/deploy_timestamp.txt
      echo `date +%s` > /var/app/deploy_timestamp.txt
```

I read it in `ruby` like this:

```
deploy_time = Time.at(File.read('/var/app/deploy_timestamp.txt').to_i)
```